# angular-translate translate dict in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

In my app I use https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate for localization. But I cant't understand how to translate dict values in my controller:

```
$scope.rx_usart_names = [
    {'val': 0, 'name': 'UART 1'},
    {'val': 2, 'name': 'UART 3'},
    {'val': 3, 'name': 'UART 4'},
    {'val': 5, 'name': 'UART 6'}
];
```

Then I show it in template like:

```
<md-select placeholder="Receiver Port" ng-model="RFDump.set.rx_usart">
  <md-option ng-repeat="option in rx_usart_names" ng-value="option.val">
    {{ option.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

If I use:
`$translate.instant('UART 1')` then when I change language, my value not changed.

If I use `$translate('UART 1')` then it returns promise.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ayqoeuyy/6/

Comment: Have you defined some keys with `$translateProvider` in your `app.config()`? Check [i18n docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/)

Comment: Here you are the example  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayqoeuyy/4/).

Comment: I added http://jsfiddle.net/ayqoeuyy/5/

Comment: @The.Bear also, why keys cannot have blank spaces ?

Comment: the problem that $translate.instant('UART 1')  not changed, when i change language programmatically

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, if you use string keys like `"UART 1": "U"`, the keys could have blank spaces... I understand your problem. I will try to resolve it in the new fiddle that you've given to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the translate filter...

**`translate` FILTER SOLUTION:** ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayqoeuyy/16/)) 
 
 
HTML:

```
<md-select>
  <md-option ng-repeat="option in vm.rx_usart_names">
    {{ option.name | translate }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

APP CONFIG:

```
app.config(function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    UART1: 'UART1 (English)',
    UART2: 'UART2 (English)'
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    UART1: 'UART1 (German)',
    UART2: 'UART2 (German)'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function MyCtrl($translate) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.rx_usart_names= [{
    'val': 0,
    'name': 'UART1'
  }, {
    'val': 2,
    'name': 'UART2'
  }];

  vm.changeLanguage = function(langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey);
  };
}
```

*I know that is not the fastest way to use a filter if you have many keys to translate, but even in the example of the [angular i18n docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/13_custom-loaders) they're using it. This is not a pure controller solution, but at least it works well. I hope someone post a better way to do it... Good luck*